# How to use soundmanager2 wilth rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, soundmanager2

I have installed soundmanager2 within my rails application as a plug in.

after installation, I tried following command to use sound manager

```
rails generate sound_manager2
```

it shows generator not found error :(

Experimenting with rails 3 but actually wants to use with rails 2 and ruby 1.8.6

Anybody know, how it works under rails ? or is there any other way to play sound with rails app ?

Answer (score 4):

Manually add the following SoundManager2 files to `vendor/assets/javascripts/soundmanager2`:

- `soundmanager2-nodebug-jsmin.js` (or one of the [other scripts](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/getstarted/), depending on your needs)
- `soundmanager2.swf`
- `soundmanager2_debug.swf`
- `soundmanager2_flash9.swf`
- `soundmanager2_flash9_debug.swf`

And then you should have either `//= require tree .` or `//= require soundmanager2/soundmanager2-nodebug-jsmin` in your application's JavaScript manifest file (`app/assets/javascripts/application.js`).

**Or alternatively**, just use the [soundmanager-rails](https://github.com/glaszig/soundmanager-rails) gem. I haven't used it myself, so I can't vouch for whether it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can just drop the JavaScript and / or Flash files from the soundmanager2 download into your rails app, the plugin is just a JavaScript wrapper, you don't need it at all.

Then follow the offical [Getting started guide](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/getstarted/)